# removing duplicate in a column with same value?

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
   url                          link
1.247appliances.co.uk   info@247appliances.co.uk info@247appliances.co.uk
2.365electrical.com sales@365electrical.com sales@365electrical.com sales@365electrical.com sales@365electrical.com|customerservices@365electrical.com sales@365electrical.com
```

in the above table first row and second row link column has repeated values but in need the result to be

```
  url                          link
1.247appliances.co.uk   info@247appliances.co.uk 
2.365electrical.com sales@365electrical.com customerservices@365electrical.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Used `DISTINCT` when calling column here is sample

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name,column_name
FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be an exact solution to your issue but I have tried to give you an idea.
Cheers

First create a Split Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split (@sep CHAR(1), @s VARCHAR(512))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
    WITH Pieces(pn, START, stop) AS (
      SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @LinkValue)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT pn + 1, stop + 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @LinkValue, stop + 1)
      FROM Pieces
      WHERE stop > 0
    )
    SELECT pn,
      SUBSTRING(@LinkValue, START, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-START ELSE 512 END) AS Link
    FROM Pieces
  )
```

I have created a temporary table for sample data (use your own table)

```
CREATE TABLE #RemoveDuplicateWords (URL VARCHAR(200), Link VARCHAR(200))
  GO
 INSERT INTO #RemoveDuplicateWords(URL,Link)
 SELECT '1.247appliances.co.uk',   'info@247appliances.co.uk info@247appliances.co.uk'
  UNION ALL
SELECT '2.365electrical.com','sales@365electrical.com sales@365electrical.com sales@365electrical.com'
GO
```

And Finally a SELECT query

```
SELECT 

    rd.URL,
    st.Link

FROM #RemoveDuplicateWords rd
CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(' ',rd.LINK) AS st
GROUP BY
    rd.URL,
    st.Link
```